# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, reactjs, fetch-api

currently, I am trying to add Google Auth to a React Application. I am able to get the information and send it to the Backend (RoR) Once in the back I send back a Token to my React front end but I keep getting: `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0`. I've been stuck on this for a while now with no luck. Maybe you guys can help out.

I tried making the ajax request with `Fetch` and `Axios`. I've tried writing the ajax request different ways, no Luck. I found similar articles with a similar error: `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`, but I checked my network tab and I am correctly getting back JSON, so I really don't understand what the problem is.

Here is the fetch snippet:

```
googleResponse = async (info) => {
const data = {
    first_name: info.w3.ofa,
    last_name: info.w3.wea,
    email: info.w3.U3,
    picture: info.w3.Paa,
    access_token: info.accessToken
}

const headers = new Headers()
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers
}
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/auth', options)
const returnedData = await response.json()
returnedData.then(r => console.log(r)) // -> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0
};
```

Here is my network tab:

[image]

I'm going to keep looking but If anyone sees what I did wrong I would be a big help.

React Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { GoogleLogin } from 'react-google-login';
import config from './config.json';

class App extends Component {

constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { isAuthenticated: false, user: null, token:''};
}

logout = () => {
    this.setState({isAuthenticated: false, token: '', user: null})
};
onFailure = (error) => {
  alert(error);
};

googleResponse = async (info) => {
    const data = {
        first_name: info.w3.ofa,
        last_name: info.w3.wea,
        email: info.w3.U3,
        picture: info.w3.Paa,
        access_token: info.accessToken
    }

    const headers = new Headers()
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers
    }
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/auth', options)
    const returnedData = await response.json()
    returnedData.then(r => console.log(r)) // -> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0
};

render() {
    let content = !!this.state.isAuthenticated ?
        (
            <div>
                <p>Authenticated</p>
                <div>
                    {this.state.user.email}
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button onClick={this.logout} className="button">
                        Log out
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        ) :
        (
            <div>
                <GoogleLogin
                    clientId={config.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}
                    buttonText="Login"
                    onSuccess={this.googleResponse}
                    onFailure={this.onFailure}
                />
            </div>
        );

    return (
        <div className="App">
            {content}
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default App;
```

RoR Code:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
def auth
    secret = 'pineapple'
    @token = JWT.encode params["data"], secret, 'HS256'
    render json: @token
end
end
```

Comment: You should post the json that's being returned since that's what's generating the error.

Comment: I don't think that error message you are receiving in the console is your console.log in the then statement. Try chaining a .catch onto your .then statement, and log the error

Comment: If there is an `'e'` at position 0 then it's clearly not valid json. Look at the actual response body in browser dev tools network and see what's there

Comment: @charlietfl  you're right, I was a small error on the rails side. instead of `render json: {toke: @token}` i did `render json: @token`. Wow